# Изменение названия файлов в PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Задача такова: у нас есть папка task лежит на рабочем столе C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\task.
В этой папке находятся 7 файлов, при том в каждом файле находятся числа не по порядку, необходимо переименовать файлы в цикле, чтобы название файла соответствовало содержимому. 
содержимое в папке - содержимое в файле 
  1.txt - 6
  2.txt - 7
  3.txt - 8
  4.txt - 9
  5.txt - 0
  6.txt - 1
  7.txt - 2

Задачу описывают таким образом: Якобы мы поехали в отпуск и наделали настолько много фото, что номера файлов стали перезаписываться с самого начала. И теперь фото с отпуска в России лежат рядом с фото прошлого отпуска в Америке.

Необходимо чтобы было текстовые файлы с содержимым отображались вот так
содержимое в папке - содержимое в файле 
  1.txt - 0
  2.txt - 1
  3.txt - 2
  4.txt - 6
  5.txt - 7
  6.txt - 8
  7.txt - 9

Пытался что то сообразить с помощью Windows PowerShell ISE

```
cd C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\task
Write-Output "Begin"

$files = get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\task"


for ($i=3; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    if ($i -ge $files.Count){

        Rename-Item -Path $files[$i] -NewName {$_.Name -replace $files[$i + 1], 'A.txt'} 


    }

}
Write-Output "End"
```

Но как вы уже поняли, раз вы это читаете ничего не вышло. Буду признателен за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Если ты друг мой, пришёл из неведомых земель и тебя заинтересовал сей вопрос. Могу ответить на него я теперь. Узри же великий код древних !

```
param(
$path="C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\task"
)cls

gci $path -file|%{ren $_.fullname a$_};gci $path -file|sort {gc $_.fullname}|%{ren 
$_.fullname $([string]++$i+$_.extension)}

"РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: ";gci $path -file|% {$_.name+" - "+(gc $_.fullname)}
```